# Controller & Routes error - Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error I am getting is this: Couldn't find User without an ID

I am effectively trying to have a user's courses be listed out on their home page when they sign in.  However I can't get the @ user to work properly in the controller, and I believe its a routing error but not sure

Static Pages Controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) <<<here is the problem
  @courses = @user.courses
 end
end
```

View Partial

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span8">
   <% if @courses.any? %>
  <ul class="courses">
    <%- @courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= link_to course.title, course_path(course) %>
    <%- end%>
  </ul>
   <% end %>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Routes.rb

```
Serenity::Application.routes.draw do

root to: 'static_pages#home' 

# match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
# match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
# match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

devise_for :users
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

resources :users do
  member do
    get :courses
  end
end
resources :courses
resources :assignments, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your routes, I can see you're using `Devise` for authentication. This means you most likely have already a helper called `current_user` giving you the `User` currently signed in.

I'm guessing you're trying to display on the home page all the courses of the current user. So change your controller action like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
  @courses = current_user.courses
 end
end
```

Comment: This made the view work, but my problem is that now my rspec tests are all failing. I have devise helpers included, but still fails. Failure/Error: before { visit root_path} NoMethodError: undefined method courses' for nil:NilClass # ./app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:in home'

Comment: my problem was that I was using this on static pages controller, in which case there was a user sometimes and other times a user didnt exist yet, and it was trying to get the courses for a user that didnt exist yet.   So ultimately i changed the method to @courses = current_user.courses if signed_in?, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your root page going to `static_pages#home`, but there is no `id` parameter in that case, so `params[:id]` is returning `nil`, so that's what's being passed to `find`. Assuming you want to access the `id` of the currently logged in user, you need to get at it some other way, as discussed in http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial. Search for `current_user` in that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any `params` on your home page. Use the built-in `current_user` method from Devise.

Comment: This works on the view itself, but my problem is that now my rspec tests are all failing. I have devise helpers included.  Failure/Error: before { visit root_path}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `courses' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'

Comment: You have to update your specs also. Login a user with devise test helpers and you will have your current_user..